# laravel won't work on shared hosting for a missing file

Tags: laravel-5

hey I have got this error

> file_put_contents(G:\recent\blog\storage\framework/sessions/nvp1wC71v9aLo2eIDFsgRvgamAGZWcPtGmW68CHM):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

when I tried to get the site to work on the shared hosting after uploading it 
and no clue what to do??

Answer (score 0):

try running "php artisan cache:clear".

It seems the sessions are stored in a cache. You may alternatively delete it manually by going to storage->framework->sessions and then empty the sessions folder.

Hope it helps.